# Using jQuery with node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have found out that you can use jQuery with node.js but all examples are for DOM and HTML manipulation.

Do you think using it for array iterations ( for each ) etc would be ok or a bit overkill?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Underscore.js is a much smaller utility library for manipulating objects.

http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/

```
npm install underscore
```

EDIT:

However, node.js has much better support for ES5 than browsers, and it's likely that you may not even need a library for manipulating objects. See keeganwatkins' answer.

Comment: You really should double check you need underscore, ES5 can do most of the what underscore can.

Comment: That's true, but stuff like `_.extend` isn't in ES5, and underscore uses the native ES5 if it's available.

Comment: `Object.keys(source).forEach(function(key) { target[key] = source[key]; });` You don't need `extend`

Answer (score 14):

Most of the common jQuery utilities are already in implemented in the V8 engine, which node.js is built on.

for example, compare:

- [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) with [Array::forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) with [Array::map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [$.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) with [Array::indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
- [$.trim](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) with [String::trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

One of the best things about node.js is that most of the ES5 spec is already there.

Comment: It's not because of the links, it's because you haven't learned to use [markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) yet.

Comment: well, when i tried to submit the original answer it said i don't have enough rep to post more than two links.

thanks for cleaning it up though!

Comment: ah, in that case, i've updated your answer to be linked correctly as they were legit.

Comment: Just to point out. At least presently $.map works with objects too. So it's not the same as using Array::map.

Answer (score 3):

NodeJS already has all the EcmaScript 5 Array Extras builtin. For example if you want all the odd squares:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].map(function(n){
    return n*n;
}).filter(function(n){
    return n%2;
});
//-> [1, 9, 25, 49, 81]
```

If you would like to see the other methods on the arrays, you can go to my [JavaScript Array Cheat Sheet](http://kaleb.hornsby.ws/comp/lang/javascript/Array-Cheat-Sheet).

If you want the sum of all the cubes, you can:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].map(function(n){
    return n * n * n;
}).reduce(function(p, n){
    return p + n;
});
//-> 2025
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has some nifty non-DOM features you can borrow -

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src

Just strip out what you do not need (like a reference to window).

Answer (score 0):

If there are just a few functions you want to add, an alternative to adding a full library is to just implement the functions you want:

Many functions that are partially supported on some browsers are documented in MDN with compatibility code that can be used to add the function: [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Compatibility)

Comment: I don't know Node.js that well, if it already has `forEach` then why would it need to be added at all via jQuery?